# HL7 RIM sample data

Tags: hl7

Hi I just generate a normalized Rim  database  using this schema.

[image]

Is that possible for me to get the sample data for all these tables?

Answer (score 1):

No that's generally not possible. You could potentially find some sample HL7 CDA R2 documents and shred them out into a normalized form for insertion into your database, but that would probably be pointless.

In practice a normalized schema based on the RIM doesn't really work. The structures go so many levels deep that you have to do lots of joins and it's impossible to build a performant application. Usually a better approach is to shred out just the pieces you need for your application and store those in individual columns, then save the rest of the document in an XML column.